# Issues handling multiple calls at the same time

Tags: c#, lync, ucma

```
private void Recorder_ExecuteCode(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        fileName = "";
        SendMail = false;
        CallIsAlive = true;
        Recorder recorder = new Recorder();

        // Use the call ID as the filename and create a media sink.
        Random rnd = new Random();
        fileName = string.Format("C:\\recordings\\Inbound Call\\EmergencyCall {0}.wma", DateTime.Now.Day.ToString() + "." + DateTime.Now.Month.ToString() + "." + DateTime.Now.Year.ToString() + " - " + DateTime.Now.Hour.ToString() + "." + DateTime.Now.Minute.ToString() + "." + DateTime.Now.Second.ToString() + rnd.Next().ToString());
        WmaFileSink fileSink = new WmaFileSink(fileName);
        Console.WriteLine("Recording for 10 seconds.");

        // Set the recorder to use the media sink and attach
        // it to the flow.
        recorder.SetSink(fileSink);
        recorder.AttachFlow(Program.MyCall.Flow);


        // Start recording.

        recorder.Start();
        SendMail = true;
    }
```

The above piece of code sets up a recorder that attaches to the audiovideoflow of the inbound call.

The issue im having is that if 2 calls come in at the same time and try and call the Recorder_executeCode function, the program crashes here:

```
        recorder.AttachFlow(Program.MyCall.Flow);
```

Visual Studio reports the following error:

InvalidOperationException was unhandled by user code.
AudioVideoFlow is already bound to a Recorder.

How would I go about changing the code to allow more than one copy of the function to run at the same time if two or more callers call in at the same time.

**Edit**

The issue was being caused by using the global variable: MyCall

I fixed the issue by setting the filename string using the Call.CallId

```
 private void Recorder_ExecuteCode(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string fileName;
        SendMail = false;
        Recorder recorder = new Recorder();

        // Use the call ID as the filename and create a media sink.
        //Random rnd = new Random();
        fileName = string.Format("C:\\recordings\\Inbound Call\\EmergencyCall {0}.wma", acceptCallActivityInboundCall1.CallProvider.ToneController.AudioVideoFlow.Call.CallId.ToString());
        WmaFileSink fileSink = new WmaFileSink(fileName);
        Console.WriteLine("Recording for 10 seconds.");


        // Set the recorder to use the media sink and attach
        // it to the flow.
        recorder.SetSink(fileSink);
        recorder.AttachFlow(acceptCallActivityInboundCall1.CallProvider.ToneController.AudioVideoFlow);


        // Start recording.

        recorder.Start();
        SendMail = true;
    }
```

Comment: It sounds like you are trying to access a shared resource (normally not allowed). Are you asking how to do cross-process synchronization?

Comment: Can you clarify a little?  The question title suggests you're having trouble running multiple instances of the same program at the same time.  The body seems to indicate that you're having trouble running the same method more than one time, but in the same process.  I'm guessing it's the latter.  What is Program.MyCall.Flow?  How is it declared?  When/how is it set?

Comment: The above code attaches a recorder to the call, and allows the caller to record audio. The issue i'm having is that if 2 callers call at the same time and attempt to record audio at the same time, the program crashes and reports AudioVideoFlow is already bound to a Recorder.

Comment: Yes - I know that.  Can you clarify how Program.MyCall.Flow is declared and how/when it is set?  It looks like a static (global) variable.  Shouldn't each call have its own AudioVideoFlow?  That would seem to preclude the use of a global variable to track the current call if you're expecting to handle more than one call at once.

Comment: @PeteBaughman You're right. The issue was being caused by a static global variable. I've fixed the issue by using the Call.CallId of each call. Problem solved.